# c++: what exactly does std::remove_pointer do?

Tags: c++

I have encountered the following line:

```
std::weak_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype(myPublisher.get())>::type> captured_pub = myPublisher;
```

I assume that "remove_pointer" removes the pointer and returns the object itself but that's only an assumption. And this is done to eventually point the object with a weak_ptr?

I was trying to understand what "remove_pointer" does, but couldn't find a satisfied explanation.
Can someone explain this line of code?

Comment: Wow, what a monstrosity.

Comment: `std::remove_pointer<T>::type` is the type that `T` points at. So, for example, `std::remove_pointer<int*>::type` is `int`.

Comment: Your line is a convoluted version of `std::weak_ptr captured_pub(myPublisher);`

Comment: `remove_pointer` operates on types, not objects. Given type `T *`, it gives you just `T`.

Answer (score 8):

Working from the inside out:

- `myPublisher` must be a variable of type `std::shared_ptr<T>` (where `T` is some unknown *type* in this case). `myPublisher.get()` thus returns a `T*` pointer variable that points to some `T` object that the `shared_ptr` shares ownership of.
- `decltype(...)` returns the *type* of the variable/expression it is given. In this case, the return value of `get()`, thus it returns the `T*` *type*.
- `std::remove_pointer<...>::type` removes the `*` from the specified *type*. In this case, returning the `T` *type*.
- `std::weak_ptr<...>` is then declared with that *type* as its template argument. In this case, `std::weak_ptr<T>`.

So, for example, let's say `T` is some class named `Publisher`, so `myPublisher` is an object of type `std::shared_ptr<Publisher>`, and so `myPublisher.get()` returns a `Publisher*` pointer, so `captured_pub` is a `std::weak_ptr<Publisher>`.

```
  std::weak_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype(myPublisher.get())>::type> captured_pub = myPublisher;
= std::weak_ptr<std::remove_pointer<decltype(Publisher*)>::type> captured_pub = myPublisher;
= std::weak_ptr<std::remove_pointer<Publisher*>::type> captured_pub = myPublisher;
= std::weak_ptr<Publisher> captured_pub = myPublisher;
```

Another way to determine `T` would be to simply use the `shared_ptr::element_type` member instead, eg:

```
std::weak_ptr<decltype(myPublisher)::element_type> captured_pub = myPublisher;
```

Or, simply let the compiler deduce `weak_ptr`'s template argument based on the type of `shared_ptr` being assigned to it, eg:

```
std::weak_ptr captured_pub = myPublisher;
```